# Express-Validator Conditional Validation

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to validate if user check any checkbox of template and if user check the checkbox then which checkbox he/she checked. I am able to validate single checkbox but having problem in validating multiple checkboxes.

I tried oneOf() function but it gives error shown below. I am open to other ways of solving this.

```
app.post('/menu-detail/:id', [
    oneOf([
    check('menu_price_large', 'required').equals('large'),
    check('menu_price_regular', 'required').equals('regular'),
    check('menu_price_xlarge', 'required').equals('xlarge'),
    ])
], (req, res)=>{
    const errors = validationResult(req)

    if(errors.isEmpty())
    {
        res.send('worked...')
    }
    else
    {
        res.send('error')
    }

})
```

Error image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to import the functions from `express-validator`.

To the validation to work you must import function `check` and `oneOf` from `express-validator`

```
const { check, oneOf, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/menu-detail/:id', oneOf([
    check('menu_price_large', 'required').isIn(['large']),
    check('menu_price_regular', 'required').isIn(['regular']),
    check('menu_price_xlarge', 'required').isIn(['xlarge'])
    ]), (req, res)=>{
        const errors = validationResult(req)

        if(errors.isEmpty()){
            res.send('worked...')
        } else {
           res.send('error')
        }
    })
```